# Private to public IP address for use with Asus VPN InstaGuard

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I have gig fiber to an ONT to a TP Link Er605 router in my coms box outside. I have an ASUS AIMESH system behind that which says my IP address is private because it’s behind the TP Link.

I want to be able to use Asus VPN InstaGuard but I’m not able to because the IP is private.

I read on the Asus website that I can fix this problem by port forwarding.

I have tried to port forward on the TP link and the Asus router and can’t seem to figure this out.

Comment: “ASUS routers with Instant Guard use virtual private network (VPN) technology to create a secure data tunnel over a public WiFi connection.” I think the fact you are using a TP-Link router precludes the fact you can’t use [ASUS VPN InstaGuard](https://www.asus.com/us/content/instant-guard/). It seems to need to be used with an ASUS router.

Comment: The network you describe seems to be at least double NATed if not triple NATed port forwarding will be next to impossible in that network configuration

Comment: My TP link is directly connected to the internet and has a public IP, it is giving my main ASUS router its private IP. If I bypass the TP link, I can achieve what I asking about. The only reason I have the TP link before my ASUS is because idiots built my house and I want to run a wired backhaul to my other wireless routers.